# codeigniter query resulting to null but the if condition doesn't satisfies

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am new in codeigniter and i am stuck with this if statement. I am selecting from my database the user_status and the user_type of the user and if it is null the value $res cant be empty.

```
if(empty($res)) {
            echo "aaaa";
            $this->index();
        }
```

here is my full code in model :

```
<?php

class Login_model extends MY_Model {
    function validate($data) {

        $condition = "user_email =" . "'" . $data['useremail'] . "' AND " . "user_password =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'";

        $this->db->select('usertype_id,user_status');
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->where($condition);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else {
            return NULL;
        }


    }
}
?>
```

my controller looks like this :

```
function validate_credentials() {
        $this->load->model('login_model');

        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );

        $res['res'] = $this->login_model->validate($data);


        if(empty($res)) {
            echo "aaaa";
            $this->index();
        }
```

My question is, why this $res is always not empty. when i `print_r` the `$res` it shows an empty array.

Comment: Change `$query = $this->db->get();` to `$this->db->count_all('my_table');`

Comment: `$res` can't be empty, you assigned a key pair value in there, `$res['res'] = NULL;`

Comment: @aldrin after changing sir ?. it will go to null ?

Comment: @Ghost hello sir, how would i assign it to satisfy in my condition

Comment: When you `print_r($result)` outside if statement what do you get?

Comment: i got an empty array sir, btw, how can i condition for example i want to get the usertype_id only sir $res->usertype_id ?

Comment: What if you use isset() instead of empty(), if(!isset($res)){}

Comment: thank you guys.. please provide an answer for me to check it. i already got it. its an object